# Why can't my second router (in DMZ) automatically find DNS settings?

Tags: dns, wireless-router, nat, cable-modem, dmz

I'm trying to set up my own router after the ATT modem/router combo. There is no bridge mode to bypass the ATT router.

So I set up the DMZ to point to my personal router and wasn't able to get any internet. When I manually enterend my ISP's DNS server, it start to work again.

Does anyone know why I have to manually enter the DNS? I feel like this isn't the best thing to do and could lead to problems/security issues down the road (what if they change it?).

Comment: It would seem that the AT&T router doesn't pass the default DNS settings to the DMZ? Many people don't use their ISP's DNS anyway because of the nefarious things they tend to do with them or at least they cut corners so they aren't as responsive. Try Google DNS or OpenDNS instead.

Comment: out of interest, is your second router(i.e. the downstream one), the one further from the wall, is that getting its IP via DHCP from the first router? or is it getting its IP statically